# How to find the most frequent key in a dictionary, and then the most frequent value

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with strings as keys, and also strings as values. First, I want to find the most frequent key in my dictionary. Second, I want to find the most frequent value in my dictionary.

I have a lot of words from a long text as different keys, and then a value to that key with what part of speech the word belongs to.

But here is an example of what my dictionary might look like:

```
dicts = {"hello":"hey", "hello":"hi", "hey":"hi", "howdy":"hello", "yo":"hi", "hello":"howdy"}
```

So, obviously, I want my code to find that "hello" is the most frequent key. And that "hi" is the most frequent value.

I have tried this to find the most frequent key:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for d in dicts.values():
    c += Counter(d)

print(c.most_common())
```

But then, it finds the most frequent letters it seems like... How to I make my code find the most frequent key, and then afterwards, the most frequent value?

Thanks!

Comment: `c = Counter(ordbok.values())` and most frequent key isn’t possible as each key is unique

Comment: nope, the initial dict is invalid - you can't have duplicate keys like `"hello":"hey", "hello":"hi"`. Therefore, you can't find most common key at all

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as "most frequent key" in a dictionary. In dictionaries, each key must be unique. As for the values, this should work just fine:

```
from collections import Counter
keys = Counter(dicts.values())
mode = keys.most_common(1)
```

Or if you're using python 3.4 and above:

```
from statistics import mode
most_common = mode(dicts.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

First : One key have only one value in Python. If you want to store a list of value, use "list"
If you want to get all value to calculate the frequency, use `my_dict.values()`. It will return a list of all values in your dictionary.
This loop will count and save it into another dict :

```
frequency = {}
for value in my_dict.values() :
    if value in frequency :
        frequency[value] = frequency[value] + 1
    else :
        frequency[value] = 1
```